# parsing multidimensional arrays into google sheet through Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have this code at a client side HTML to export html table into array and submit it to gapi.

```
function exportGsheet() {
    var myTableArray = [];
    $("#table tr").each(function() {
    var arrayOfThisRow = [];
    var tableData = $(this).find('td');
    if (tableData.length > 0) {
    tableData.each(function() { arrayOfThisRow.push($(this).text()); });
    myTableArray.push(arrayOfThisRow);
    }
    });

    var request = {
        'function': 'setData',
        'parameters': myTableArray,
        'devMode': true // Optional.
    };

    var op = gapi.client.request({
        'root': 'https://script.googleapis.com',
        'path': 'v1/scripts/' + SCRIPT_ID + ':run',
        'method': 'POST',
        'body': request
    });

    op.execute();
    window.open(gsheet);
//  alert(myTableArray)
}
```

And this code in Google Apps Script (published as API executable) to parse this arrays and populate the cells in google sheet.

```
    function setData(e) {
      var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(DOC_ID);
      var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
      var row = [];
      for(var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
        row.push(e[i]);
        }
     sheet.getRange(5, 2, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);
}
```

The arrays looks like this

```
[["John","10","Lakeview","12345"],["Jill","8‌​","Tramble","12346"],["James","9","Paramount","12348"]]
```

The issue here is that the google apps script populates only the first row and ignores the rest of the arrays. Means, it populates `["John","10","Lakeview","12345"]` array into the first row and ignores all other arrays.
I had enabled console.log() in the client javascript and I could see that the request body contains all the arrays when it is passed to gapi. Below is the console.log() of 'op' variable above.

```
body : "{"function":"setData","parameters":[["John","10","Lakeview","12345"],["Jill","8‌​","Tramble","12346"],["James","9","Paramount","12348"]],"devMode":true}"
```

Trying to debug this for several hours. Can anyone please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 3rd parameter for:

```
getRange(start row, start column, number of Rows, number of columns)
```

is the number of rows.  You have it set to one:

```
sheet.getRange(5, 2, 1, row.length).setValues([row])
```

It needs to be set up like this:

```
getRange(5, 2, data.length, data[0].length)
```

The last parameter should reference an inner array length.

The array that is now named `row`, I would change to something like `OuterArray`.

```
var outerArray = [];

for(var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
  outerArray.push(e[i]);
}

sheet.getRange(5, 2, outerArray.length, outerArray[0].length).setValues(outerArray);
```

Comment: Works like a charm.. Thanks a ton Sandy.. Plz remember to add JSON.stringify() in source html and JSON.parse() in apps script. Parsing arrays directly wont work.